# RequestMapping GET and POST methods handling in Spring REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have such code:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String testPost(@RequestParam("param1") String param1, @RequestParam("param2") String param2) {
        return param1 + param2;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    String testGet(@RequestParam String param1) {
        return param1;
    }
}
```

And I execute such `curl` expressions:

```
curl --verbose http://localhost:9000/foo?param1=Sergei
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9000 (#0)
> GET /foo?param1=Sergei HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:9000
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 29 Dec 2015 08:55:56 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"timestamp":1451379356514,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/foo"}
```

and,

```
curl --verbose --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://localhost:9000/foo
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9000 (#0)
> POST /foo HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:9000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 27
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 27 out of 27 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Allow: HEAD, GET
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 29 Dec 2015 09:01:46 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"timestamp":1451379706832,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/foo"}
```

Help me please get both my methods work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `RestController` or `Controller` stereotype annotation to your `Application` class like this:

```
@RestController
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
...
}
```

**Note:** You can use `SpringBootApplication` meta annotation instead of those three, so you would have:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the scope level of the two controller methods to `public`. Right now, they don't have any, so the methods are `package local` by default.

`public String testPost(@RequestParam("param1") String param1, @RequestParam("param2") String param2) {`

`public String testGet(@RequestParam String param1) {`

Comment: The problem is the `Application` is **NOT** even a `Controller` (or `RestController` for that matter), so changing the visibility would not have any effect. By the way, the default visibility is `package local` not `protected`.

Comment: sorry, my bad- will correct it. by the way, did changing to public help?

Comment: He should add a `RestController` annotation for his `Application`.

Comment: oh yeah, just saw that he is even missing the `RestController` annotation.

Comment: @ketan, `public` or `package local` doesn't matter. I have checked